# Syntax Error while using parse

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, argparse

The name of my function is getTile.py. I am trying to use the argparse function in python to parse stuff from the command line. However, the program can't get past the second line of my script. It keeps coming back in the command line with this:

```
./getTile.py: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./getTile.py: line 19: `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
```

I am following the argparse gentle tutorial on python.org. Also, this is my program.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("X-coordinate", help="Please put in the X-coordinate of your point.", type=float)
xCoordinate=float(parser.X-coordinate)
def aFunction(var1):
    var1 = var1+5
    print(a)
afunction(xCoordinate)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, please add the code required to reproduce your error [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure you're running Python? Because that looks more like an error message that might be generated by bash. Have you been able to successfully run Python programs before this one?

Comment: I have added the code-cheeerrrs

Comment: You are missing `args = parser.parse_args()`. But there are more problems. You cannot use a dash in a variable name in python. That will be interpreted as a minus sign. You can work around that by using `getattr`. Like this: `xCoordinate = float(getattr(args, 'X-coordinate'))`

Comment: thank you, but this still did not solve the problem...:(

Comment: Yep, that's definitely a shell error message, not a Python error message.

Comment: NEVERMIND, all my fault!! forgot to tell the program that i was writing in python....

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
In [42]: import argparse
    ...: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ...: parser.add_argument("X_coordinate", help="Please put in the X-coordinate of your point.", type=float)
    ...: args = parser.parse_args('1.23'.split()) # simulate commandline
    ...: print(args)
    ...: xCoordinate=args.X_coordinate   # type already converted it to float
    ...: def aFunction(var1):
    ...:     var1 = var1+5
    ...:     print(a)
    ...: aFunction(xCoordinate)
    ...: 
    ...: 
Namespace(X_coordinate=1.23)
3.141592653589793
```

With a dest like `X-coordinate` you have to use `getattr`, because that isn't a valid variable name.  But for a positional you don't need to use a fancy `dest`.  A simple string is just as good.  (For a optional, a flag like '--X-coordinate' is ok.)

I also dropped the unnecessary `float`.

During testing I like to use `print(args)` to get a clear idea of what the parser is doing.

The syntax error is not reproducible from your code.

Answer (score 0):

The file is currently being executed as a shell script resulting in the error.

Try:

```
python ./getTile.py
```

Or add this to the header (1st line in the getTile.py):

```
#!/bin/env python
```

Add add execute permissions:

```
chmod u+x getTile.py
```

Then try:

```
./getTile.py
```